# my flutter app is refusing to run when adding audioplayers dependencies

Tags: flutter

the flutter app is not running when i add audioplayers to the dependencies in pub file
but it works when i remove it from the dependencies

it shows this Exception:

```
> Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'.
   > The current Gradle version 6.7 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.7.1 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can update your gradle version, so for that you can check all the available versions on below link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?gclid=CjwKCAiAheacBhB8EiwAItVO2_F66xegnNqO5Wd2ruBlRa2jgBpCLw-QuciP-4OwhL4IIcnM2n-_5xoCls4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#groovy

and you can update to latest kotlin version according to below link:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#apply-the-plugin

Comment: i have tried but it did not work

Comment: can you share snippet of gradle-wrapper.properties file in your question. You can find gradle-wrapper.properties file inside your flutter project -> android -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

Comment: I had updated my gradle and flutter sdk but it did not work

Comment: @mohammedLutf share your gradle version and kotlin version once

Comment: which is the one u r referring to (in what folder )

Comment: your flutter project -> android -> build.gradle you will find "ext.kotlin_version" & "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'". Share these 2 things

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }

Comment: @mohammedLutf  use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3' and use can also update ext.kotlin_version if you will get error about it then with the link you can find appropriate version https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#ide-support

Comment: thanks alot i have been using gradle:7.3 but it shows an error telling me to update android and jave so  i will try again the moment i update my java version and android and see if it work, again thanks